# Prove or disprove that there exists a function f : N → N such that, for every graph G, we have χ(G) ≤ f(ω(G)).

Tags: coloring

Prove or disprove that there exists a function f : N → N such that, for every graph G, we have χ(G) ≤ f(ω(G)).

Here in my question, χ stands for the chromatic number and ω stands for the clique number.

I know ω(G)≤ χ(G), and I clearly understand the definition of chromatic number and clique.

But I am not sure where to start with this question.

I guess such a function does not exist, but how should I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: If you believe there is no such function, then a reasonable strategy would be to find a family of graphs where the clique number is fixed but the chromatic number can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian for instance